# Elucidation On one foot

Tags: ahavat-yisrael, hillel, ahavat-hashem

The story of Hillel's response to the potential convert who wanted the entire Torah taught to him while standing on one foot is well known. Hillel was able to summarize the Torah in the maxim, "What is hateful to you, do not do to others" ([Shabbos 31a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=31&format=pdf))

While certainly the main point of Hillel's teaching was simplicity, do we find any major treatments of this teaching among the Rishonim (though I wouldn't begrudge anyone who wanted to mention major discussions among the Achronim either :) )?

Comment: The rest of Hillel's summary is important too: "now go and study".

Comment: That's why I asked for perushim. ;)

Comment: Also, if you want there is a book called Matan Torah written by Rav Yehuda Ashlag where he has an entire chapter on this.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28420

Answer (score 4):

- Keli Yakar Sefer Wayikra 19:27 writes

על כן ביקש ממנו שימסור לו כלל אחד הכולל כל התורה ועל דרך המליצה אמר כשאני עומד על רגל אחת, וכוונתו למסור לו דבר הנאמר מהרה בלשון קצר והיינו גם כן יסוד ורגל אחת ועל ידי שיזכור כלל זה יזכור את כל מצוות ה':

Summary: Therefore he asked him to teach him one principal that contains everything in the Torah. Through a allegory he said "on one leg" and he wanted some quick and short so he will remember this and if he remembers this he will remember all of Hashem's commandments.

- Malbim ibid. writes the same thing

מעשה בההוא גר שאמר למדני כל התורה כשאני עומד על רגל אחת ולמדו הלל פסוק ואהבת לרעך כמוך כל דעלך סני לחברך לא תעביד ואידך פירושא זיל גמור. וכפי הנראה שהגר היה גר צדק ולא היה מהתל התולים לומר בדרך שחוק שילמדו כל התורה בעוד שהוא עומד על רגל אחת ממש, אלא ודאי ביקש ממש שיעמיד לו כל מצוות התורה על יסוד אחד דהיינו רגל אחת אשר עליו יעמיד לו כל המצוות כדי שלא יבוא לידי שכחה המצויה בגר אשר לא למד מנעוריו כלום ...

Summary: ...so he won't come to forget.

- Torah Temima Bereshit ch. 5 (footnotes)

והכונה דכמו שעליך שנוא זה שיעבור על דבריך כך לא תעבור אתה על מצות ה' שבאת ללמוד תורתו, וזה הוא יסוד התורה

Summary: Just like you hate when people go against your words don't go against the words of Hashem, and this is the foundation of the Torah.

- Derashot HaRan , Derasha 5

אמרו (שבת לא א) על אותו שבא לפני הלל ואמר לו שילמדהו כל התורה על רגל אחת, והשיבו ואהבת לרעך כמוך (ויקרא יט יח) , ואידך גמרא הוא זיל גמור, רצו בו שמי שיקבע בלבו זאת התכונה הטובה, יקלו עליו עניני רוב המצוות.

Summary: He said this to instill in his heart this one idea, and then other Miswot will look easy in his eyes.

- Menorat HaMaor ch. 17

והאוהב את הבריות כאלו קיים כל התורה כלה, כדגרסי' בפ' במה מדליקין מעשה בגוי אחד, שבא לפני הלל. אמ' לו, גיירני על מנת שתלמדני תורה על רגל אחת. אמ' לו, ואהבת לרעך כמוך.

Summary: "One who loves Hashem's creations is like he fulfilled the entire Torah." Therefore he said "teach me the Torah on one foot" and Hilel answered "Love your neighbor like yourself."